# creating .bat file for java

Tags: java, file, batch-file

I need to create a .bat file to run java program.
I have a DatabaseConnect.class file under "C:\Program Files\Java" directory.
And I have a jar files for database connection in "C:\Program Files\JarColl" directory.

I tried but no success .
ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: can you tell us what did you try?

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't suggest storing class files in your Program Files\Java directory - it's bound to get very messy after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely Path problem.

Try this?

```
java -classpath "C:\Program Files\JarColl\\*";C:\Program Files\Java DatabaseConnect
```

Comment: There is a space between 'Java' and 'DatabaseConnect'

Comment: why there is a double quote for jars and not for class name.
is that the only line i need to put in the .bat file.

Comment: @user234194: Without double quotes java will interpret a space character as the end of the classpath parameter. As the name of the class doesn't/can't have spaces, it doesn't need quotes. As for your second question, that should be all you need to put in the .bat file (although, I'd suggest you just try it rather than coming back here and asking - it's much faster).